# docker swarm - if the container in a service dies on an error, will the task be replicated elsewhere?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose, docker-swarm

In a docker swarm environment what will happen if the container dies because of an internal error? Will the task be reborn?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

With Swarm Mode introduced in 1.12, the orchestration will run a new container on another node when it detects the target state doesn't match the current state.

With the prior container based Swarm solution, the Swarm itself won't restart the container, but the host running the container may restart it if you pass a flag like `--restart=always`.